# how to track how many click in google analytics using jquery

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, tracking, event-tracking

I'm trying to track how many people are clicking on a link to a certain page. I don't know if it's working or not. I tried console.log but I don't know if I'm doing it correctly.

html

```
<div class="nav-wrapper">
<div class="nav">
<a class="scroll" href="#heading1">HEADING 1</a>
<a class="scroll" href="#heading2">HEADING 2</a>
<a class="scroll" href="#heading3">HEADING 3</a>
</div>
</div>


<div class="heading1">Heading 1</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris luctus ultrices adipiscing. Nunc suscipit ultrices est, vel pharetra metus. Maecenas condimentum metus vitae metus rutrum vehicula. Morbi porttitor consequat tincidunt. Aliquam elementum ac nisi vel blandit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Integer dapibus egestas purus sed euismod. Vivamus vel nisl in ante venenatis porttitor. Mauris at egestas tortor.</p>
<div class="heading2">Heading 2</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris luctus ultrices adipiscing. Nunc suscipit ultrices est, vel pharetra metus. Maecenas condimentum metus vitae metus rutrum vehicula. Morbi porttitor consequat tincidunt. Aliquam elementum ac nisi vel blandit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Integer dapibus egestas purus sed euismod. Vivamus vel nisl in ante venenatis porttitor. Mauris at egestas tortor.</p>
<div class="heading3">Heading 3</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris luctus ultrices adipiscing. Nunc suscipit ultrices est, vel pharetra metus. Maecenas condimentum metus vitae metus rutrum vehicula. Morbi porttitor consequat tincidunt. Aliquam elementum ac nisi vel blandit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Integer dapibus egestas purus sed euismod. Vivamus vel nisl in ante venenatis porttitor. Mauris at egestas tortor.</p>
<div class="heading4">Heading 4</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris luctus ultrices adipiscing. Nunc suscipit ultrices est, vel pharetra metus. Maecenas condimentum metus vitae metus rutrum vehicula. Morbi porttitor consequat tincidunt. Aliquam elementum ac nisi vel blandit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Integer dapibus egestas purus sed euismod. Vivamus vel nisl in ante venenatis porttitor. Mauris at egestas tortor.</p>
```

my jquery

```
function tracker(trackVal){
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-tracking number");
if($.trim(trackVal) != ""){
pageTracker._trackPageview(trackVal);
}
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {



$("#heading1").click(function(){
tracker($.trim("heading 1"));
consol.log('#heading1');
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add it as an event and track the event that way.   [Event Tracking - Web Tracking (ga.js)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide)

The code will look something like this:

```
<a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Baby\'s First Birthday']);">Play</a>
```